# excel that automatically convert cell range to picture on another sheet and automatically update

Tags: asp.net, windows, excel

I want to creat an excel workbook that can convert cell rang on a sheet to picture on another sheet and is capable of authomatically updating the picture should there be any modification on the source sheet. I have no macros background.

Comment: Please, be more specific.

Comment: Hi Nicolai, I have a table on a sheet, and I want to insert this table as a picture on several sheets, such that when I update the table on the source sheet, the pictures on the several other sheet will authomatically be updated. Do u understand?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that you can adapt.  We want to capture changes to range **C3:F10**

These are input changes rather than the result of calculation.

If the cells in this block are changed, the block is copied as Picture and the Picture pasted in *Sheet3* near cell **C5**

Insert the following Event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, sv As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set r1 = Range("C3:F10")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C5")

    If Intersect(Target, r1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set sv = Selection
    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        r1.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        Sheets("Sheet3").Select
        On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Latest Snap").Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        r2.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Selection.Name = "Latest Snap"
        sh.Select
        sv.Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I have gotten my way around it. All I did was copy and past special as linked picture on the other sheet and all the worries were over.....